# How to refactor Python header?

Tags: python

At first my colleague used header begin with project name `cdmop`

```
from cdmop.apps.authentications.views import LoginView, logout_view, ChangePasswordView
```

And now I want to remove `cdmop` from the header. I have searched on topic of refactor. I found that my pycharm can refactor it for me, but I have to hit command enter one by one or use multi cursors

I want to know the best way how to solve my case. They are 20 directories with five or more files in one directory.

Comment: I...I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Hold on I am rewriting my question

Comment: @JackManey Hi I am back

Comment: I still don't really know what you're trying to do. If you don't want to import anything from `cdmop.apps.authentications.views`, then....don't. However, make sure you're not using `LoginView`, `logout_view`, or `ChangePasswordView` within the given module.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to remove `cdmop` from this line? I mean, if you remove it, everything's likely to break...

Comment: Here is what I want `from apps.authentications.views import LoginView, logout_view, ChangePasswordView`

Comment: @ForceBru I would not break because I copy source to docker container

Comment: In PyCharm, you should be able to refactor the `apps` subpackage in the tree view, moving it up one level in the package hierarchy. Keep in mind that this will likely break things all across your project if there's stuff in `cdmop` that is needed in `cdmop.apps`.

Comment: I can set PYTHONPATH=cdmop to let python start from that level then header will not has prefix `cdmop`. Right now I want to know the other way around that not use multi cursor and delete

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring is not really related to language (Python in this case) but mostly to IDE or editor used (PyCharm in this case).

If you want to remove the top level module 'cdmop' in your imports, then you whant to take the module 'apps' containing 'authentications.view' and move it to the parent folder. PyCharm can do this for you. Right click on the module, and select Refactor > Move. After the module (or package) has been moved, other modules importing it will be updated with the new path.

Comment: Yes I know it will automatically refactor for me. I use PyCharm with my defined PYTHONPATH to mimic docker environment. However, it does not my case

Comment: I don't know what "it does not my case" is supposed to mean.

Comment: My case I can not move directory level. Since that level will be gone anyway when I copy to the docker container

Comment: Well, then you can't do the refactor that you want to do.

Comment: @JackManey Arh I have to use multi cursor anyway. Thank you very much.